# Select data uploaded in last 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

I want to select data from my table that was uploaded in the last 7 days. Here is what i have so far but it is not working.

```
$sql9="SELECT SUM(TruckDamage) 
WHERE DATEDIFF(`upload_date`, CURRENT_DATE) < 7 
AS     TotalTruckDamageSum FROM jwtdriversbank2";  
$result9=mysql_query($sql9);
$rows9=mysql_fetch_assoc($result9);
$sum8=$rows9['TotalTruckDamageSum'];
?>
<div>
Total Truck Repair Cost's: &pound;<?echo $sum8?><br>
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: WHat is the issue u r getting?

Comment: Try `CURRENT_DATE()` (with parentheses). `CURRENT_DATE` is a function. Oh according to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) what you have now should work. (Apart from other issues)

Comment: And where's `FROM` ? Why it's after `WHERE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your query is invalid. You are assigning TotalTruckDamageSum to `WHERE`. Second syntax error is that `FROM` should be before `WHERE`. And last but not least is that bigger date should be first if you want to get non-negative result of `DATEDIFF`.

Should be:

```
$sql9="SELECT SUM(TruckDamage) AS TotalTruckDamageSum FROM `jwtdriversbank2` WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,`upload_date`) <= 7";
```

Comment: That appears to have worked i just need to do some maths to check that it has selected the right ones lol

Comment: This depends... you can use `<= 7` or `< 7` or even `< 7` and `not 0` to avoid counting of today data. The `< 7` means u are getting today and 6 days before today, `<= 7` means u get today and 7 days before today and `WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,upload_date) <= 7 AND DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,upload_date) != 0` means u get 7 days before current day and not today.

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
sql9="SELECT SUM(TruckDamage) 

AS     TotalTruckDamageSum FROM jwtdriversbank2 WHERE DATEDIFF(`upload_date`, CURRENT_DATE()) < 7";
```

Comment: I just tried that code and it just selects them all completely ignores the datediff bit

Comment: Please try my answer. Everything is explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql9="SELECT SUM(TruckDamage) AS     TotalTruckDamageSum 
                  where upload_date >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
                  FROM jwtdriversbank2";  

$result9=mysql_query($sql9);
$rows9=mysql_fetch_assoc($result9);
$sum8=$rows9['TotalTruckDamageSum'];
?>
<div>
Total Truck Repair Cost's: &pound;<?echo $sum8?><br>
```